# Get the output from flask to display in html

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

I successfully added the `yolov5` model in `flask` with an alarm. However, I want to display in the web the output from Python. However, using a flask is very hard and difficult for me. I have three file, camera.py (where the detection process), `main.py` (flask server), and `index.html`

camera.py:

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.play_sound = False
        
    def play_sound_async(self):
        playsound('alarm.mp3')

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        fps = int(self.video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = model(image, size = 240)
        
        a = np.squeeze(results.render())
        if len(results.xyxy[0]):
            labels = results.pandas().xyxy[0]['name']
            if 'fire' in labels.values:
                print('Fire detected!')
                
                # labels, cord_thres = results.xyxyn[0][:, -1].numpy(), results.xyxyn[0][:, :-1].numpy()
                # x = cord_thres[:, 0]
                # y = cord_thres[:, 1]
                # w = cord_thres[:, 2]
                # h = cord_thres[:, 3]
                # print(x,y,w,h)
                
                if not self.play_sound:
                    # Play the sound asynchronously
                    self.play_sound = True
                    threading.Thread(target=self.play_sound_async).start()
                
                # Save the image
                cv2.imwrite('fire_detected.jpg', cv2.cvtColor(a, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                message = f'Fire detected at {now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}'
                # Send the image via Telegram
                with open('fire_detected.jpg', 'rb') as f:
                    bot.send_photo(chat_id='ID_key', photo=f, caption=message)
                
        else:
            self.play_sound = False
            print('no fire detected')
            
        cv2.waitKey(fps)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
    
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

index.html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="camera">
            <img class="bg" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
            <h2>Camera 1</h2>
        </div>
```

I want to display on the web if there is a fire detected. Thanks